# Making use of an XML file with more than one root element

Tags: xml, ms-access

I have an XML file with multiple root elements transferred to me from a third party.  I would imagine that the third party in question has a reasonably good idea of how to structure XML files.  Is there any way that this isn't a mistake on their part and that there is a way to, for example, import such a file into Access or another database system?  The file contains multiple repetitions of the same XML tags with different values for different entities.  Would there be a way to import these all at once so each XML tag creates a table populated by all entities?

Comment: A well-formed XML file has a single root node. If you're getting more than one, you'll need to either wrap it properly in an outer root node or inform your third party that they're giving you XML that is not well-formed.

Comment: ... or split it up into multiple files each with a single root node.

Comment: @Jim I was thinking about doing this too, but my issue (which is probably more trivial) is how to easily import the 100+ XML documents into, say, 7 tables in Access.  I know importing one XML document will give me a nice structure and the tables will already be set up, but if I have 100 won't I just have 100 duplicates of those 7 tables?

Comment: @Ken Thanks Ken, I was thinking of doing that as a worst case scenario.

Comment: Perhaps you can pre-process your data before importing it. Add a root node and then pass it through a parser or XSLT processor to organize your data structures.

Comment: @helderdarocha How hard would it be to learn to use an XSLT processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an XML file with multiple root elements

Well, your file is not an XML document, but (if you're lucky) it is an XML external general parsed entity, so you can parse it by creating a dummy XML document that references it as an entity. You need a skeletal document like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE orders [
<!ENTITY e SYSTEM "datafile.xml">
]>
<doc>&e;</doc>
```

I don't know what input you need for Access, but once you've got a document like this you can use XSLT to transform it into the desired format.